# split int and bool values in two different lists

Tags: python

I have the following list:

```
a = [1104537600, 1199145600, False, 1199145600, 1443886293, True]
```

and I want to split this list to two sublists such as:

```
[[1104537600, 1199145600,1199145600, 1443886293],[False,True]]
```

I am using the following which give that result:

```
b = [value for value in a if type(value) is int]
c = [value for value in a if type(value) is bool]
d = [b,c]
```

But is there a more elegant way? In one line?

Comment: Looks pretty elegant to me.

Answer (score 3):

Your attempt is pretty and understandable ,more of it you can combine both ur b and c in only one statement as :

```
d=[[value for value in a if type(value) is bool ],[value for value in a if type(value) is int ]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the traditional for loop. By this way, you don't need to iterate over the same list for two times.

```
>>> num, b = [], []
>>> for i in a:
    if type(i) is int:
        num.append(i)
    elif type(i) is bool:
        b.append(i)


>>> num
[1104537600, 1199145600, 1199145600, 1443886293]
>>> b
[False, True]
>>> [num, b]
[[1104537600, 1199145600, 1199145600, 1443886293], [False, True]]
```

Comment: But is it more elegant? Safe very extreme cases, it won't matter for performance if you iterate it once or twice.

Answer (score 0):

I guess doing it in one line would be less elegant actually.
Keep  in mind that the most important - if we don't consider performances - is that someone (or you in the future) can easily understand your code.

This one is easily understandable, and not wrong, I would go for it for sure

Answer (score 0):

You could build the `d` list up as follows:

```
a = [1104537600, 1199145600, False, 1199145600, 1443886293, True]
d = [[], []]

for value in a:
    if type(value) is int:
        d[0].append(value)
    elif type(value) is bool:
        d[1].append(value)    

print d
```

Giving:

```
[[1104537600, 1199145600, 1199145600, 1443886293], [False, True]]
```